# SelectionchageHandler called on columnSort in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have added a selectionchangehandler() to Datagrid, but the onSelectionChangeEvent() gets called even if click on column Header, The list is sorted using column header and i have used a keyprovider to persist my row selection.

```
/*this is code used to add selectionmodel*/ 
selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<ConferenceInfo>( keyprovider );
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler( new Handler()
{

@Override
public void onSelectionChange( SelectionChangeEvent event )
{
selectedConference = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
currentselectionindex = dataprovider.getList().indexOf( selectedConference );
}
} );

directoryList.setSelectionModel( selectionModel );//directorylist is my datagrid

directoryList.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy( KeyboardSelectionPolicy.BOUND_TO_SELECTION );

/*Also when datagrid appears to jump upwards when last row is selected*/

sorthandler.setComparator( corganizer, new Comparator<ConferenceInfo>()//corganizer is textcolumn
    {

        @Override
        public int compare( ConferenceInfo arg0, ConferenceInfo arg1 )
        {
            if( arg0.getHostName() != null && arg1.getHostName() != null )
            {
                return arg0.getHostName().compareToIgnoreCase( arg1.getHostName() );
            }

            return -1;
        }
    } );

    sorthandler.setComparator( ctitle, new Comparator<ConferenceInfo>()//ctitle is textcolumn
    {

        @Override
        public int compare( ConferenceInfo arg0, ConferenceInfo arg1 )
        {
            if( arg0.getTitle() != null && arg1.getTitle() != null )
            {
                return arg0.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase( arg1.getTitle() );
            }

            return -1;
        }
    } );
```

Thanks,

Comment: Sorting should not result in SelectionChange event. Something is going on in your code. Show the code for your DataGrid.

Comment: Hi andrei, I have added the code, but i want to know what possibly could go wrong in this case, also it happens arbitrarily

Comment: I don't see any problems here. What about your SortHandler?

Comment: Does it have something to do with how i have initialized my Textcolumn?

Comment: How many records do you have and how many do you show?

Comment: I get the records from server, they are generally in the range of 50-70, In my code i have not set the visible row count and KEYBOARDSELECTIONPOLICY is set to bound to selection.

Comment: I don't understand the reason, but when I changed the KEYBORADSELECTIONPOLICY to enabled in my singleselectionmodel, this odd behaviour stopped.